# Datatables, how to sort a table so a specific row is always the first row?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I got a small question.
My datatable uses AJAX to gather the rows for my table, the table sort on 6th. column.

Is it possible to always have a specific row to be first? No matter how the sorting is gone?
It does not matter if the row change position after the initial sorting.

My code looks like this:

```
$('#servertable').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "/objects.php",
    "deferRender": true,
    "order": [[ 5, "desc" ]],
    "pageLength": 25,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { 
            "data": "hostname",
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                $(nTd).html("<a href='/"+oData.url+"'>"+oData.hostname+"</a>");
             }
        },
        { "data": "version" },
        { "data": "country_cn" },
        { "data": "map_id" },
        { "data": "players" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I think you want to implement [Sorting with absolute positioned](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-12-22)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of the cases, where a custom sorting plugin is in its place. I guess you want to have certain players on top of the list, all the time? If you have an array of player names which should stay on the top :

```
var players =  ['Yuri Berry', 'Vivian Harrell'];
```

then you can implement a sorting plugin like this :

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "players-on-top-asc": function( a, b ) {
    a = ~players.indexOf(a) ? new Array(255).join('a') : a;
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  },
  "players-on-top-desc": function( a, b ) {
    a = ~players.indexOf(a) ? new Array(255).join('z') : a;
    return b.localeCompare(a);    
  }
});
```

usage :

```
$('#servertable').DataTable( {
  ...
  "columns": [
    ...
    { "data": "players", type: "players-on-top" }
  ]
});
```

see a small demo, look for column #2 -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ryfce85u/**